# Can't show the DataTemplate on a selected item in combobox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

Newbie question. In the following combobox, the drop-down list correctly displays the company name and phone number as per the DataTemplate. However, selecting an item from the drop-down (by mouse) resutls only in showing the object name:

```
  Stargate_V.DataService.View_Small_Company
```

The selected company name and phone number is not shown. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <ComboBox 
  ItemsSource="{Binding PrimaryInsurance.Companies}"
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CompanyTemplate}"
  IsEditable="True"
  IsTextSearchEnabled="True"              
  Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="375,235,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="198"  />
```

The CompanyTemplate is:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CompanyTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Companyname}" Width="240"/>
                <TextBlock Text="|" Width="10"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Phone}" Width="80" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

TIA

Comment: If you don't want text to be editable you can set `IsEditable` to False and it will solve your issue,

Comment: @RohitVats Down the line, I will need to accept user input as I am headed toward an autofiltering combobox. So I will need IsEditable to true. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you are having is the combination of displaying a complex type (i.e. Class) with a `DataTemplate` and your `ComboBox` has `IsEditable` set to true. When setting `IsEditable` to true the `ComboBox` doesn't know which property to use for searching so it just calls `ToString` on the object and displays the results. To fix this issue you need to set the `TextSearch.TextPath` to the property name on the object that you would like to use for searching. Once you do that it will display that property in the selection box instead of the result of `ToString`. Below is what your XAML should look like if you wanted to search on the `Companyname` property on your object.

```
<ComboBox 
  ItemsSource="{Binding PrimaryInsurance.Companies}"
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CompanyTemplate}"
  IsEditable="True"
  IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
  TextSearch.TextPath="Companyname"              
  Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="375,235,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="198"  />
```

Comment: I see the initial link, but the link to the full example seems broken. So I will have to make a new control?

Comment: No you should be able to just assign your CompanyTemplate to that property like you did for the ItemTemplate and be good to go.

Comment: SelectionBoxItemTemplate is read-only. The property 'ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate' cannot be set because it does not have an accessible set accessor. :(

Comment: Oh my bad, I was looking that up on my phone. So since your ComboBox is editable and you are using a complex object for display there is no way to search that complex object in a ComboBox so you need to choose a property to allow for searching using TextSearch.TextPath property on the ComboBox. This [link](http://www.shujaat.net/2010/08/wpf-editable-combobox-with-datatemplate.html) explains it more.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. (Please edit your answer so I can credit you.) :)